# Glimpse and Tracing using TraceSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, trace, glimpse

I'm trying to get my traceoutput to appear in the Trace tab for Glimpse; I'm using TraceSource to output my tracing currently to a file with code like :

```
    public static void TraceEvent(TraceEventType type, string area, string message)
    {
        TraceSource ts = new TraceSource(TraceSourceName);

        if (Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            if (type != TraceEventType.Verbose)
            {
                Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
        }

        ts.TraceEvent(type, 0, string.Format("{0}: {1}", area, message));
    }
```

This does seem to appear in the tab but if i swap out the ts.TraceEvent line with Trace.Information for instance.

Is there a custom listener I should be using or does it only work with the Trace command?

Comment: This question is being discussed on GitHub: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/210

Comment: Support for TraceSource was added in [Glimpse 1.0](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse/), release Feb 20, 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Glimpse supports `TraceSource` via the `Glimpse.Core.TraceListener`, which must be configured in `web.config`.

Full instructions and a sample are available on the [Trace Tab help page](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Trace-Tab) on the [Glimpse website](http://getglimpse.com/).

Comment: `Trace Tab help page` is 404.